# Difference in meaning and prononciation of urbane and urban

Tags: differences, pronunciation, connotation

I encounter these two words pretty often, both orally and in writing.  What is the difference between two, and how to pronounce, say in USA?

Comment: US Pronunciation: *urbane* = "er-BAYN" [ɚˈbeɪn], *urban* = "ER-buhn" [ˈɝ bən].  Note that the words have stress on different syllables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Urbane has a more subjective meaning. Urban means something that relates to the city, while urbane describes a level of sophistication and elegance that supposedly would be typical for city folk.

Answer (score 2):

urban means posh and well developed, of course, talking about a city while urbane has more to do with his mannerisms- reflecting sophistication and class.

Answer (score -1):

*Urban* is more city related, whereas *urbane* refers to the manners of the people in a city.